# Error while implementing google plus login in android application

Tags: java, android

I got this error while implementing Google Plus Api login through Android application ,How can we resolve this error ,please help me out in resolving this proble,I have generated access tokens from google developer console,but I don't have any idea where to use them .And it always gives me the same results for several times when we executed.

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable700Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:dexDebug
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpa$zza;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 5.056 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

And My build.gradle Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.health.weshallovercome"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'

}
```

Comment: Try to remove this line : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'.

Comment: I have removed  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'. in the build.gradle file ,it gives unfortunately app has stopped  error

Comment: Okay then replace this line : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0' with this 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'.

Comment: Though I am getting the same response

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing a similar problem. I think the problem is that play-service is a bundle of all the libraries which also include play-service-plus. The Plus button should work without importing

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
```

But you should not do this, you should import only that part of the play-service this is required.
Also after removing the

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
```

don't forget to clean build the project and build it again.